# In `Python 3`, get maximum of first m elements and last m elements from a list of integers

Tags: python-3.x

In `Python 3`, how to get maximum of first m elements and last m elements from a list of integers n times (omitting the previous maximum value) efficiently?

say

```
arr=[10,20,35,30,10,45,0,20,25,50,15]
m=4
n=3
1<=array size<=10^5
0<=array element<=10^9
1<=n<=array size
1<=m<=array size

First m elements = [10,20,35,30]
Last m elements = [20,25,50,15]

0th element of the output list --> maximum of above i.e. 50

after omitting 50
arr=[10,20,35,30,10,45,0,20,25,15]
First m elements = [10,20,35,30]
Last m elements = [0,20,25,15]
1th element of the output list --> maximum of above i.e. 35

and so on... upto (n-1)th element
```

I tried using basic logic and its working fine for small inputs, but got timeout error as list size,m,n can be upto 10^5. is there any python specific shortcuts to achieve it efficiently?

Code #1

```
for i in range(0,n):
    if len(arr)>2*m+n-i-1:
        temp=arr[:m]+arr[-m:]
    else:
        temp=arr
    x=max(temp)
    ind=temp.index(x)
    if ind>=m:
        ind=ind-len(temp)
    arr.pop(ind)
    print(x)
```

code #2

```
l=len(arr)
for j in range(0,n):
    acnt=0
    bcnt=0
    ai=0
    bi=-1
    x=-1
    while acnt<m and ai<l:
        if arr[ai]!=-1:
            if arr[ai]>x:
                x=arr[ai]
                i=ai
            acnt=acnt+1
        ai=ai+1
    while bcnt<m and bi>=-l:
        if arr[bi]!=-1:
            if arr[bi]>x:
                x=arr[bi]
                i=bi
            bcnt=bcnt+1
        bi=bi-1
    print(x)
    arr[i]=-1
```

Also I tried using recursion and sorting, but I am still getting Timeout error for large test cases. Is there any other solution with less complexity?

Comment: if you have huge amounts of integers, and these integers don't have to be unlimited size, then you probably should not be using lists in the first place, there are numpy arrays for that.

Comment: One question, if you have `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0]` and `m = 2`, what should the result be for `n = 2`? `2` (`[1, 2, <9>, 0]` -> `[1, <2>, 0]`) or `8` (`[1, 2, <9>, 0]` -> `[1, 2, <8>, 0]`)?

Comment: for `arr=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0], m=2 and n=2` result array should be [max([1,2]+[9,0]), max([1,2]+[8,0)] i.e [9,8]

Comment: I edited my answer, check if it works, and please answer in a comment at my answer so that i get notified.

Comment: @Adirio I have tried another approach by removing extra loop overheads and it is working fine. Thanks for your help though and I will definitely try your code as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
m = 4
n = 3
arr = [10,20,35,30,10,45,0,20,25,50,15]

# From Start
for x in range(n):
    maximum = max(arr[:m])
    arr.remove(maximum);
    print(maximum)

arr = [10,20,35,30,10,45,0,20,25,50,15]

# From End
for x in range(n):
    maximum = max(arr[m+1:])
    arr.remove(maximum);
    print(maximum)
```

Slice the list to the m-th element and take it's maximum and after that remove the first occurrence from the initial list.

Since it removes the maximum element from the array and assuming those ranges might overlap, there is the need to initialize the initial array twice. Unless you know they won't overlap.

Or if the goal is to take max from the beginning and from the end in turns then it can be easily modified to:

```
m=4
n=3
arr=[10,20,35,30,10,45,0,20,25,50,15]

for x in range(n):
    maximum = max(arr[m+1:]) # From End
    arr.remove(maximum);
    print(maximum)
    maximum = max(arr[:m]) # From Start
    arr.remove(maximum);
    print(maximum)
```

Obviously there might be a better solution.

You could possibly speed up the process by using some sort of memoization and dynamic programming. Keep track of sub-array values in sorted order, for easy access to the next maximum and only add/remove those one by one.

Or create some custom data structure to keep track of local maximum.

Also check this:
[Finding maximum in sliding window](http://p-nand-q.com/python/algorithms/searching/max-sliding-window.html)

Comment: For this part of your code,

    `maximum = max(arr[m+1:]) # From End
    arr.remove(maximum);
    print(maximum)`

if same element is present in somewhere in the beginning then it will remove that element, not from the last m elements.
Rest of my code is almost similar as yours but I am getting Timeout error for large values of m,n and big array.

Comment: @SaikatSen use a stack or a queue (In a list implementation) and create a custom node to keep track of the max element so far... every time your "window" moves forward update the last node... it will be a lot faster, but I cant be bothered to code it for you, sorry.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. That 'Queue' word triggered a good idea somehow and the problem is solved now. I have post the solution that worked for all the test cases.

Answer (score 0):

A full implementation could be like the following:

```
import itertools

def f(array, m, n):
    l = len(array)
    if l <= 2 * m: # The full array fits in the first iteration
        temp = sorted(array)
        for i in range(-1, -min(n,l)-1, -1):
            yield temp[i]
    else:
        i = m          # Next element from the start
        j = l - m - 1  # Next element from the end
        temp = [(array[k], k) for k in itertools.chain(range(i), range(j + 1, l))]
        for _ in range(n):
            temp.sort()
            max, index = temp[-1]
            yield max
            if i > j:  # Check that we haven't crossed the indexes
                break
            if index < i:
                temp[-1] = (array[i], i)
                i += 1
            else:
                temp[-1] = (array[j], j)
                j -= 1

# Usage
print(list(f([10, 20, 35, 30, 10, 45, 0, 20, 25, 50, 15], m=4, n= 3)))
# [50, 35, 30]
print(list(f([10, 20, 35, 30, 10, 45, 0, 20, 25, 50, 15], m=4, n= 4)))
# [50, 35, 30, 45]
print(list(f([10, 20, 35, 30, 10, 45, 0, 20, 25, 50, 15], m=4, n=10)))
# [50, 35, 30, 45]
print(list(f([10, 20, 35, 30, 10, 45, 0, 20, 25, 50, 15], m=4, n=12)))
# [50, 35, 30, 45]

print(list(f([10, 20, 35, 30, 10, 45, 0, 20, 25, 50, 15], m=10, n= 3)))
# [50, 45, 35]
print(list(f([10, 20, 35, 30, 10, 45, 0, 20, 25, 50, 15], m=10, n= 4)))
# [50, 45, 35, 30]
print(list(f([10, 20, 35, 30, 10, 45, 0, 20, 25, 50, 15], m=10, n=10)))
# [50, 45, 35, 30, 25, 20, 20, 15, 10, 10]
print(list(f([10, 20, 35, 30, 10, 45, 0, 20, 25, 50, 15], m=10, n=12)))
# [50, 45, 35, 30, 25, 20, 20, 15, 10, 10, 0]
```

Comment: Option 2 is O(length^2). Option 1 requires sorting, which is not as bad but still overkill for small n. Proper solution is something like https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.partition.html

Comment: @SargeBorsch Option 2B is `O(n * (2*m)^2)` while Option 1B requires sorting a 2*m-elements list (not sure about the underlying sorting algorithm complexity, `O(2*m*log(2*m))`?). The length of the initial list should not affect the complexity in either way. Plus I dont think @jpp answer is correct.

Comment: hmm probably I misread the answer at the first time. surely if len(temp) = m then it's like you wrote.

Comment: I tried using sorting and also see the codes I tried in the question. None of them are working for large test cases.

Comment: @SargeBorsch `len(temp) = 2 * m` What I was trying to point out is that the complexity doesn't depend on `len(array)`.

Answer (score 0):

Finally removing the extra loop overheads, it is working fine for all test cases. Thanks for the help guys.

```
f=0
r=len(arr)-1
f_flag=1
r_flag=1
for i in range(0,n):
    if r<=f+2*m-1:
        arr[f:r+1]=sorted(arr[f:r+1],reverse=True)
        f=f+n-i
        break
    else:
        for j in range(0,m-1):
            if f_flag==1:
                if f+j+1<len(arr):
                    if arr[f]<arr[f+j+1]:
                        x=arr[f]
                        arr[f]=arr[f+j+1]
                        arr[f+j+1]=x
            if r_flag==1:
                if r-1-j>=0:
                    if arr[r]<arr[r-1-j]:
                        x=arr[r]
                        arr[r]=arr[r-1-j]
                        arr[r-1-j]=x
        if arr[f]>=arr[r]:
            f=f+1
            f_flag=1
            r_flag=0
        else:
            r=r-1
            f_flag=0
            r_flag=1
return(sum(arr[:f]+arr[r+1:]))
```